# SharePoint hit counter is not displayed

Tags: 2007, usage-counters

I followed the instructions here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825532

After that when I preview my page, I can't see the hit counter. I learned that it may be related to permissions of the site but I couldn't find how to do it.

Is it really related to permissions? If so what should I do to it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this](http://nspsharing.blogspot.com/2009/11/hit-counter-sharepoint-designer-is-not.html) link? It talks about the hit counter being no longer available with MOSS SP2.